# 12V from Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, power

I don't think it's possible, but I want to drive my 433 MHz transmitter (FS21000A) from a 12V 'supply', to get more power (and thus more range).

However, I don't have an external power supply. I can add an adapter (12V/1A) to my Arduino with the barrel input, but I wonder where to get 12V from? I only see 5V or 3.3V outputs.

And as far as I know all GPIO output 5V ... so how can I get 12V (or maybe a bit less but more than 5V) out of an Arduino? (and what safety measurements I should take to not ruin my Arduino?)

Comment: VIN is the barrel jack less one diode drop.

Comment: So VIN is more like an output (to give power to external components)?

Comment: It is neither input nor output. It just is. Power has no concept of in or out.

Comment: Ok clear,  going to use it now

Comment: What transmitter is it?

Comment: It shows RF-5V, but it looks like the small right component in http://uploads.avc-shop.de/uploads/ebay/bilder/mhzsender-1402092733-21335.jpg

Comment: Oh, one of those. They're pretty naff really. Have you tried adding a 1/4 wavelength dipole to it?

Comment: @Majenko ... not yet ... I think I'm going to try it with two ... also ordered some (cheap) antennas for it to solder on ... I just bought these 433MHz to check, I hope in my project I can use nRF24L01 2.4 GHz, which are much faster (and hopefully more range). But if I get these to work to like 10 meters or so I can find some nice use for it later (and it's all part of learning about RF/electronics too)

Comment: I have got hundreds of meters from the nRF24L01+ modules with build in LNA and power amplifier. They work well.

Comment: @Majenko ... I ordered long time ago a cheap set of 5 ... still haven't received them but no problem to wait ... However, yesterday I ordered two with antennas and PA+LNA, think that is what you mean? https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1sets-Special-promotions-2-4G-wireless-modules-1100-Meters-Long-Distance-NRF24L01-PA-LNA-wireless-modules/32787846044.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.97LZRv

Comment: Yep, that's the ones.

Comment: I think I will get the ultra-cheap ones first, so I can already experiment with those (in close range, like max 50 cm), I hope to get error-free communication with some speed with the PA+LNA ones.

Comment: @Downvoter, can you instead of downvoting all my posts, explain WHY you downvoted, so I may improve the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In crude terms the power supply of the Arduino is along these lines:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUomSQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's actually more complex than that, especially concerning the USB power input, but that doesn't matter here.

As you can see the barrel jack (your 12V supply) first goes through a diode. Then it gets fed to the 5V regulator. The VIN pin also goes to the same pin of the 5V regulator, so it will see 12V minus the voltage drop of the diode (~0.7V).

So you can provide 12V to the barrel jack and use the VIN pin as an 11.3V supply.

Comment: It worked, thanks... however, I don't see any range increase (and also noticed I cannot upload a sketch while both USB and adapter are plugged in at the same time. 

But I learnt something (again).. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to drive my 433 MHz transmitter (FS21000A) from a 12V 'supply', to get more power (and thus more range).

that only works if the transmitter works at 12v and isn't powered through a regulator.

if not, applying 12v to it does nothing but generating some heat or damage, worse yet.

Comment: The transmitter is indeed able to work from 2-12V, and I according the scheme of Majenko the regulator is not going out of VIN (unless the regulator is in de adapter itself).

I checked, it worked, however, I don't see any noticeable gain.